# Normal distribution of $t$.

Tags: statistics

I have a population with $10000$ individuals, I took $10$ to my samples. The values that I have inside $\bar{X}$ are: 
$$\begin{matrix} 70.22502193 &  70.26042017 \\ 70.28977621 & 70.2905717 \\ 70.30113496 & 70.32304453 \\ 70.32489699 & 70.3434273 \\ 70.41455295 & 70.46876484 \end{matrix}$$

$$\mu = 50.03385, \quad \bar{X} = 70.32416, \quad S = 0.071637,\quad N = 10.$$

I need to find $P(|\bar{X}−\mu|<t S \sqrt{N})$ i used the $t$ formula $t = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{S}{\sqrt{N}}} = \frac {70.32416−50.033850} {\frac{0.071637}{\sqrt{10}}}$, where the result was $895.677$, is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure that $\mu$ (I assume the population average) is 50... instead of 70...?

Comment: @Ragnar the total population(10000) the average($\mu$) is 50.03385, and the average from the sampling that i made(i took 10 from 10000) is 70.32416. yes, its correct, i checked using excel.